# Random forest - proof of convergence

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-forest, algorithms

I'm having some trouble understanding Leo Breiman's proof that the generalization error of a random forest converges as the number of trees increases ([here's a link to the paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/639/art%253A10.1023%252FA%253A1010933404324.pdf?auth66=1410013253_07a85cf6aed531602bd43f400a52cbd1&ext=.pdf)).

At Appendix I he states that:

> **Proof of theorem 1.2**: It suffices to show that there is a set of probability zero C on the sequence space $ \Theta_1, \Theta_2, ... $ such that outside of C, for all x,
>   $$
> \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}I(h(\Theta_n,x)=j) \rightarrow P_\Theta(h(\Theta,x)=j)  
> $$

I'm failing to understand the following:

1. The sequence space of $ \Theta $'s is a sequence space as defined in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space)? are the elements of the sequence space infinite sequences of real or complex numbers?
2. What does a "set of probability zero C on the sequence space ..." mean? is there another way to describe C?

Any help or explanation, partial or otherwise, is much welcomed.

Thanks !